# Covert SAP XSTRING to a doc file?

Tags: python, python-requests, abap, doc, python-responses

I'm working in an application which has SAP RFC which returns doc files as  XSTRINGs. And also there is a client application written in python that sends request to SAP RFC to get doc files. So my question is, in python, how can i convert XSTRING to a doc file?.

Response Header's  content type is `application/msword; and charset=utf-8`

Comment: A variable of type XSTRING is a string of bytes. If those bytes correspond to the said "doc file", why not considering them as they are. What did you try? Moreover, application/msword corresponds to the "old" proprietary format Word 97-2003, so it's made of bytes, hence it's weird that `charset` is provided.

Comment: my XTRING looks like this : e1xydGYxXGFkZWZsYW5nMTAyNVxhbnNpXGFuc2ljcGcxMjUyXHVj

Comment: This can't be a XSTRING (either it's hexadecimal digits or non-printable characters). It's **base64**. I could make sure via an [online tool](http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/) which decodes it to `{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc` which is the "old" [RTF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format). Maybe it's sent by RFC as XSTRING, and either SAP RFC or pyRFC converts it to base64. Whatever. If your program has it in base64, you should decode it and save it as an `.rtf` file and you can open it with MS Word.

Comment: @SandraRossi your answer was helpful. you are correct on base64 . thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I see that you edited your question to propose an answer to your question. I moved it to an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was given by the OP inside his own question, so I have moved it here to fit StackOverflow principles.

Answer to my own question :

Even though SAP RFC returns a variable of type `xstring`, Python receives it in base64. In order to convert base64 string to doc, first I decoded base64 string and it gave me output in RTF. Then I wrote RTF bytes to a `.rtf` file. RTF files can be opened from most of the word processing tools. Therefore I was able to open `.rtf` file from word processing tools.

Following is code I wrote for conversion:

```
    from base64 import b64decode

    base64_resp = response_json['data']
    bytes_rtf = b64decode(base64_resp, validate=True)

    f = open(rtf_filename, 'wb')
    f.write(bytes_rtf)
    f.close()
```